# Ansible | AWS Parameter Store | Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-secrets-manager, aws-parameter-store

I have ansible task in which I am passing the password value hard coded.

Ansible script:-

```
- name: Airflow
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: airflow
    password: password
    state: present
    force: yes
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  register: airflow_dbsetup
  notify:
    - restart rabbitmq-server
```

Now I have created AWS parameter store like below. How can I pass these values inside my ansible script.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`aws_ssm`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/aws_ssm.html) plugin for ansible.

Example:

```
- name: Airflow
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', 'rabbitmq_user', region='us-east-1') }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', 'rabbitmq_password', region='us-east-1') }}
    state: present
    force: yes
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  register: airflow_dbsetup
  notify:
    - restart rabbitmq-server
```